# Django view AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is communication between ajax operation and django view.

I have a form, and if I click submit button of the form the Ajax code excuted.

Ajax code:

```
function makeEvent(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var year = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(0,4);
            var month = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(5,7);
            var day = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(8,10);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'makeevent' %}",
                data: {'form': $("#makeEventForm").serialize(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    refreshCalendarAjax(year, month);
                    listevent(year, month, day);
                    document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Create new event successful." );
                },
                error: function(request,status,error){
                    if (status == 599) {
                        $("#sidebar").html = error;
                    } else {
                       console.log(error); 
                    }
                },
            });
        }
```

View Code:

```
def makeevent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST.get('form', None))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Successful", status=200)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors, status=599)
    else:
        print("NOT POST");
```

And if I try to submit a data through form, 500 error comes out and the error message is:

```
Internal Server Error: /makeevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/workspace/CalendarProject/cencal/views.py", line 42, in makeevent
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I really can't figure it out why this doesn't works :( Thanks for reading

Comment: modify your if condition to `if form and form.is_valid():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form data is serialized in the ajax request. You have to use django.http.QueryDict to deserialize it to a dict in your view function before initializing the EventForm.

Comment: You mean, by just removing ```.serialize()``` from ```$("#makeEventForm").serialize()```, It'll work properly?